# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException [ GrailsHttpSession.createQuery() ]

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hql

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import java.lang.String
import org.hibernate.Query

 // grails controller logic

String hql ="SELECT state,count(team_id) FROM Obstacle where team_id = :teamId and state IN :states group BY state";

            Query t=session.createQuery(hql);

            t.setParameter("teamId",item[0]);
            t.setParameterList("states",stateList);

            List team = t.list();
```

The above is the query i am executing.

The error I am getting is:

**Class:groovy.lang.MissingMethodException**

**Message**
**No signature of method:** org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsHttpSession.createQuery() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [SELECT state,count(team_id) FROM Obstacle where team_id = :teamId and state IN :states group BY state]

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that the variable `session` in the context of a controller refers to the `GrailsHttpSession`, and what you are looking for is the Hibernate session.

In order to get a Hibernate session you will need to use the `sessionFactory` which you can inject into your controller like this:

```
class MyController {
  def sessionFactory
  ...
  def someAction() {
    ...
    String hql = "..."
    def theHibernateSession = sessionFactory.currentSession
    Query t = theHibernateSession.createQuery(hql)
    ...
  }
...
}
```

However, since you are using Grails it's a shame you aren't using [executeQuery](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html) or any of the other means available in GORM to do the same thing.

Comment: I was using executeQuery before.... But it does not take list as an parameter for IN clause..gives error say expecting String not Arraylist .